# vertically align text based on image using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have an image and want a text next to it centered vertically. I can use text-center if its horizontal aligning but I need to align vertically. How can I do that? Is there any way in bootstrap to do this?

```
  <div class="col-md-12 well">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></img>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div>
        This text should be centered vertically
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/flyingboy007/pen/vLvVpd)

Comment: Didn't you mean align `vertically center` ? :)

Comment: Horizontally aligned center with respect to what—the viewport, or space not taken by the image?

Comment: @MehranTorki right mate..changed...

Comment: @sean vertical alignment based on the image

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
.well {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-12 well">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></img>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div>
      This text should be centered vertically
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As expected..Thanks mate..Will it support IE?

Comment: You should be able to get it to work in IE 11. You may need to use prefixes for IE 10. Try checking [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673531(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

```html
<html><head>    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-3">
    <img src="https://media.haircutinspiration.com/photos/20181204011855/boy-hairstyle-e1536810585307.jpg" class="img-fluid">
</div>
    <div class="col-3 align-self-center">
        hello hello
    </div>
 
</div>
  </body>
```

Comment: I think this the best response, and doesn't need any extra "css" added to our styles. 
Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

You should modify the css class from "col-md-3" to "col-md-9". Then you get it center, because you use as big container "col-md-12"

And Add

```
 "text-align: center"
```